# How to use if else condition with Join in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, join

I want to fetch questions of $id(dynamic,passing as parameter) and want to whether this is
"ParentbusinessId" or "businessId"

table name "nps_ques"

```
id      config_id       question
1       1               Lorem Ipsum
2       1               Lorem Ipsum2
3       1               Lorem Ipsum3
```

Table "nps_config"

```
id      parentBusinessId        businessId
1       4580                    NULL    
2       0                       2
3       4580                    3
```

I tried with following code

```
$this->db->select('nq.id as ques_id,nq.config_id as formId,nq.question,nc.parentBusinessId,nc.businessId)
                ->from('nps_ques nq')
                ->join("nps_config nc", "nc.id=nq.config_id")
                ->where("nq.config_id", $id)
                ->order_by("nq.id", "ASC");
```

Comment: Use it your condition in select()

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE.
See example below:

```
SELECT 
config.id AS config_id,
questions.question,
case when config.parent_business_id is not null then config.parent_business_id else config.business_id end as business
FROM
questions
    JOIN
config ON questions.config_id = config.id
WHERE
  config.id = 1;
```

[image]